# Google Sheets VLOOKUP/IF

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

Plain english: Output 1 (yes) if the same ID# has more than one entry in the sheet within 5 minutes.

Example sheet, feel free to change anything: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/184jhnAmu63HSYl69prnAP7xo7j2PFvzjrWgDS4zj7dU

My thought is to get VLOOKUP to output something with an IF statement. But could also VLOOKUP in column E, IF calculation in column F?

VLOOKUP: input column D, output 1 in column e when input value is between 0 and 0.00347222221898846 (5 minutes reformatted). Output 0 if >0.00347222221898846.

Then I was trying to have an IF statement parse column A so that if the same value in A is present within the last 5 minutes. But I can't really figure out the IF statement.

Something like: time elapsed is less than 5 minutes (0.00347222221898846) AND that ID# was a previous entry (within the last 5 minutes). In some instances, another ID# will be the previous entry, but still within 5 minutes, so the IF can't just look up one row.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up just using IF/AND statements and a few extra calculation columns, see example sheet.

If anyone has any more efficient methods, let me know.